# pypy without a visible console window

Tags: windows, console, window, pypy

With cpython I can run a script with a visible console window by:

```
python.exe script.py
```

or without a visible console window by:

```
pythonw.exe script.py
```

With Pypy I can run a script with a visible console window by:

```
pypy.exe script.py
```

How can I run a script in Pypy without a visible console window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed.  Reported as https://bugs.pypy.org/issue1651.

For now you can make pypyw.exe manually with a hex editor following the trick described e.g. here: [Difference between Windows and Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574911/difference-between-windows-and-console-application)

Comment: So with pypy 2.2.1 I'd need to create a pypyw.exe which is the same as pypy.exe except for that one bit referred to in the other SO?