# How to run a Python script without Windows console appearing

Tags: python, windows

Is there any way to run a Python script without a command shell momentarily appearing?
Naming my files with the ".pyw" extension doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ShellExecuteEx function.

```
BOOL ShellExecuteEx(
_Inout_ SHELLEXECUTEINFO *pExecInfo
);
```

This is the pExecInfo: 
***nShow - Flags that specify how an application is to be shown when it is opened

```
typedef struct _SHELLEXECUTEINFO {
  DWORD     cbSize;
  ULONG     fMask;
  HWND      hwnd;
  LPCTSTR   lpVerb;
  LPCTSTR   lpFile;
  LPCTSTR   lpParameters;
  LPCTSTR   lpDirectory;
  int       nShow;/*=0 if you don't want the console window to appear*/
  HINSTANCE hInstApp;
  LPVOID    lpIDList;
  LPCTSTR   lpClass;
  HKEY      hkeyClass;
  DWORD     dwHotKey;
  union {
    HANDLE hIcon;
    HANDLE hMonitor;
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
    HANDLE    hProcess;
} SHELLEXECUTEINFO, *LPSHELLEXECUTEINFO;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you got there? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try using the Python's `pythonw.exe` executable to start your script.

In Windows OSes, executables that are *console applications* (`python.exe` with out the `w` is a console app) are run showing a console window; in the other hand regular Windows applications do not spawn that black console window.

You can find the details about these two executables in this old question: [pythonw.exe or python.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe)

And about Windows different types of applications here: [Difference between Windows and Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574911/difference-between-windows-and-console-application)

Comment: Thanks,Now I am running the python file from c like this: system("python.pyw"). How should I execute  it now?

Comment: @David, `system` uses cmd to run a program, which briefly flashes a console when you run a non-console program from a non-console program. If you're not passing parameters to the script you can use `os.startfile("script.pyw")` instead. But first fix the .pyw file association. The default value of `[HKLM|HKCU]\Software\Classes\.pyw` should be `Python.NoConFile`. Then use the right-click "open with" dialog to select to always use Python for .pyw scripts. If there are multiple Python entries, try them all until it works right, but *do not* "Look for another app on this PC".

Answer (score 2):

In all python installs since 2.5 (and possibly earlier), if the install has been done properly, `.py` files are associated to `python.exe` and `.pyw` files are associated to `pythonw.exe`

If the associations have been tampered with, or overridden for a particular user, that may be different.

Run the following command in a cmd:

```
ftype | find "pythonw"
assoc | find ".pyw"
```

I get:

```
 Python.NoConFile="D:\Program Files\Python27\pythonw.exe" "%1" %*
.pyw=Python.NoConFile
```

If you don't have that, you can do several things to fix that:

1. re-install/repair python installation (run installer, it will propose to repair install)
2. if you're not administrator of your machine, you can associate `.pyw` files to `pythonw.exe`. Minor problem with that, you have to alter the registry key afterwards to add the extra arguments or dropping a parameter on your .pyw file won't take it into account (it's seldom used but still)

   `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\shell\open\command]
    @="\"L:\\Portable_Python_2.7.3.1\\App\\pythonw.exe\" \"%1\" %*"`

Comment: It's best to modify `HKLM\Software\Classes` or `HKCU\Software\Classes`. The `HKCR` virtual key is a merged view of these two trees, so the result of modifying it depends on the currently defined keys. Merging a .reg file that uses `HKCR` may modify the subkey in `HKCU` if it exists, else the subkey in `HKLM` if it exists, else create the subkey in `HKLM`. So a key and its subkeys could end up partially defined for the current user and partially defined for the local machine.

Comment: Note that cmd's `assoc` and `ftype` commands only show and modify the `HKLM\Software\Classes` keys and these keys only define one possibility for the user's selection in Explorer. There are other places file associations can be defined, such as `[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\Classes\Applications` and defaults under `[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\Classes\SystemFileAssociations`. The user's current selection is in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`, but this can [should] only be modified using the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to copy the "LazyLibrarian.py" to "LazyLibraryian.pyw" and create a shortcut to Desktop.  Then put the shortcut in your startup folder.