# I am trying to run appcfg.py from CMD. instead of deploying, its being edited in google chrome

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, cmd

I installed python 2.7.13 and the [google original App Engine SDK for PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/download). I created my first project on google console and When I am trying to deploy the project file from cmd using

`appcfg.py -A *project-id* update *project-folder*`

Instead of running, its just being edited in chrome. Please refer attached picture [chrome editing appcfg.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExjWL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are probably running Windows and have probably wrongly associated your `.py` files with Google Chrome (like it is associated to `.html` files)

Chrome acts as a text viewer in that case.

Either reinstall python (to fix associations, that would be the best thing to do, python has a "repair" option when running the installation, no need to uninstall/reinstall) or remove your user registry key:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command]
```

which must contain something wrong like:

```
@="\"C:\\Programs\\chrome.exe\" \"%1\"
```

and let system file associations take over.

or as a final workaround, if you cannot, just use `python` prefix to force python execution instead of relying on file associations:

```
python appcfg.py -A *project-id* update *project-folder*
```

(python must be in the path, and `appcfg.py` must be in the current directory or in `PYTHONPATH`)

note that the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python` doesn't help here (on Linux it would have helped)

Another way to repair associations manually is given in another [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38612907/6451573)