# Running a python file in windows after removing old python files

Tags: python, windows, directory

So I am running python 3.6.5 on a school computer the most things are heavily restricted to do on a school computer and i can only use python on drive D. I cannot use batch either. I had python 2.7 on it last year until i deleted all the files and installed python 3.6.5 after that i couldn't double click on a .py file to open it as it said continue using E:\Python27\python(2.7).exe I had the old python of a USB which is why it asks this but know i would like to change that path the the new python file so how would i do that in windows

Comment: Two possible solutions I can think of is changing the registry ```https://stackoverflow.com/a/29179765/4180176``` or updating your file associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Windows Settings --> Standard-Apps for Filetyp. There you can choose with wich program you want to open a specific filtyp, in this case ".py".

[image]

Let me know if this works :)

Comment: Worked great thank you so much

Comment: Great, I am happy for you :)

Comment: problem is that association doesn't work properly from the shell because it's lacking arguments. I answered something like this a long time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346083/i-am-trying-to-run-appcfg-py-from-cmd-instead-of-deploying-its-being-edited-in

Answer (score 0):

Just open your Python IDE and open the file manually.

Comment: I do not want to do that as it takes time and i rather double click on it ive tried uninstalling it multiple times still the same thing