# Cant pass arguments to python script run in python shell

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Windows 10 and I wrote a python script to open an external .exe program.
The python version is Python 3.6.
I use `subprosee.Popen(command, shell = True)` to run command. (If I did not inclue the shell=True parameter it won't work properly)
There is a sentence `print(sys.argv)`. When I run command like `>python program.py arg1 arg2` in windows command prompt, a python shell will be started and it got shown twice. In Command Prompt is shows:
`['program.py' 'arg1' 'arg2']`
However, in python shell it shows:
`['program.py']`
Which means the arguments are not passed into python script properly. How should I solve this?
I have searched some hints online and someone mentions the association configuration. I did the following thing:
`assoc .py=Python.File
ftype Python.File="C:\Anaconda3\python.exe" "%1" %*`
 but the weird thing is that although I can find `Python.File="C:\Anaconda3\python.exe" "%1" %*` by `ftype | findstr -i python`, it shows `File type 'Python.File' not found or no open command associated with it.` when I type `ftype Python.File`.
[image]
I also configure the register info manually.
[image: r]
So what should I do to solve this problem? Your help will be very important to me.

Comment: I expect you might need to logout-login to reload the file association information after manual editing.

Comment: I don't understand very well how you run your script when using the python shell. Could you describe it more precisely?

Comment: ftype and assoc always seemed unreliable to me. What I did is associate .py to the python exe, then find the entry in the registry and add %1 %* (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38612907/6451573)