# Difference between blank universal windows app and console app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, console-application

I have seen this excellent post [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574911/difference-between-windows-and-console-application).

As most do, I began a new simple project that has no UI requirement.  I noticed the Blank App ( Universal Windows ) option.  What is the difference between that and a Console app?

I need an executable that will do some coverting of tiff to pdf type work on a every so often basis. ( every 30 minutes )

I also do not want a service, as in this case there is no need for it to constantly run

Comment: They have nothing whatsoever in common.  There is no option to get a console window in UWP, it must always be a GUI.  "Will do some conversion work" is certainly not an appropriate UWP app job.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2686476/17034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal Windows Blank app refers to Universal Windows Platform (UWP).

It uses a subset of .Net Framework, also has some parts that aren't in .Net Framework (thanks to @DavidJ comment) and has some other app behaviour limitations. It's used for apps running on wide range of devices like Windows PC, Windows phones, Xbox and other Microsoft products.

Look at particular quote:

> Windows 10 makes it easier to develop apps for the UWP with just one API set, one app package, and one store to reach all Windows 10 devices – PC, tablet, phone, Xbox, HoloLens, Surface Hub and more.

So there's no need to use it just for *Windows_PC_only* console application.

More links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp

Comment: So if I just want an scheduled task ( No UI and not a Service) to run which is the best project type?

Comment: Good ol' `Console app` :)

Comment: The description of what a UWP application is when selecting it in Visual Studion is suckie

Comment: yeah, even googling it you'll find first Microsoft marketing blah-blah-blah. Just remember that using UWP is getting rewarded only when you *really* need its multi-device benefits or Windows Store integration or smth else because of a lot of limitations and quirks

Comment: Confused by "It uses a subset of .Net Framework" as I need a console-only app to run on Win10 to access the Windows.Devices.Sensors namespace (to provide sensor data over the network), but I don't see it listed in the .NET reference, only the UWP API reference??

Comment: @DavidJ yeah, it's UWP specific. So in your case you should choose UWP application template (Blank App, I suppose).

Comment: Now I see your point. There're parts of .Net framework that are not in UWP and there're parts of UWP that are not in .Net. So strictly speaking UWP isn't subset of .Net - they have huge common part and both have unique parts.